# ImageView hover shows text

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using a CardVIew inside there is an ImageView which if you on touch/hover/scroll,it should show some animation with text which I would be putting like an item description above image view.Bit confused what's the proper term to search on google.Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: can we have some code??

Comment: I am seeking suggestion.

Comment: @Cyborg91 Something like [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover)

Comment: yes Nisarg, just it would show description above that

Comment: @Cyborg91 Dig it up more to meet your requirement, I haven't tried yet.

Comment: You can show toast over the image by adjusting its position this can be one of the ways for doing it

Comment: @Cyborg91 have you worked this library i need help it is urgent i am stuck in this for 5 days

Comment: yup Abhishek,ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your requirement. I have found same thing that you require. This is link where you can get your card with hover animation with scroll.

**https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover**

Add dependancy in Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:20.+"
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidviewhover:library:1.0.4@aar'
}
```

Create an original view, and make sure it was wrapped by BlurLayout

for example:

```
<com.daimajia.androidviewhover.BlurLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/kid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</com.daimajia.androidviewhover.BlurLayout>
```

Note: BlurLayout is entended from RelativeLayout. You can use the RelativeLayout rules to layout your view.

Create a hover view, there is no rules to obey. Just please remember that this view will be stretched as large as the original view you have created.

Bind a hover view to BlurLayout

```
BlurLayout sampleLayout = (BlurLayout)findViewById(R.id.sample);
View hover = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.hover, null);
sampleLayout.setHoverView(hover);
```

and don't forget that you can add various animations just in one line code. For example:

```
//View (R.id.heart) appear animation.
sampleLayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover, R.id.heart, Techniques.FlipInX);
//View (R.id.heart) disappear animation.
sampleLayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover, R.id.heart, Techniques.FlipOutX);
```